# why i have to cast in stored proceure

Tags: t-sql

in my stored procedure

why i have to cast the course to varchar (not writing complete stored procedure)
while my course_id in DB is of int type , after casting it works proper what may be the reason

```
@course int =null,
    SET @query = @query + 'Where course_id='+ cast(@course as varchar)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a `VARCHAR + INT` expression, `VARCHAR` is implicity cast to `INT`, not vice versa.

This query:

```
SELECT  '12' + 345
```

will return `357`, not `'12345'`, while this one:

```
SELECT  'ab' + 1
```

will fail rather than returning `'ab1'`

If you want string concatenation, you should use explicit cast which is what you are doing.

Comment: so our complete will be always of string form isn't it? and also i want to know varchr is use for string type only

Comment: also one more confusion in  my database the type of course_id is int and i am making it to compare with the string type how does it work

Comment: @Novice: please post it is a separate question, comments are not a right place for this.

Answer (score 2):

because when you use dynamic SQL then the sql string needs to be a string data type and you can not concatenate an int to a string without converting the int. you must get the int to be a string and then add it to the rest of the string SQL query

Comment: but sir one confusion is that when i convert @course to varchar type then how come int data type column value is compared with the string type value

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could just define the variable as varchar to begin with.

If this variable can be null, then you will also have a problem because null concatenated to a string is a null.

Comment: no i am checkig for this isNull property like if @course is not null

Comment: so varchar can hold int type of value also?

Comment: Sure it can, you would want to ensure that only ints are sent to it though from the application side as the query will fail if you fill it with a value like 'a' which a varchar can also accept.